# Rewriting information on the same line

Tags: c, command-line, cmd, countdown

I am new to C programming and I wish to have a countdown take place on one line, for example, like this:

```
Time left: n
```

where `n` would be the only part of that line that was updated.

I'm talking about command line programming. I know how to do the count down, I just need help keeping it on one line and dynamically updating that line.

Comment: Not possible in pure ANSI C - what OS are you using - because you will need some libraries/extensions that allow control of placement of output (ie unix/linux you'll want ncurses)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: it's a lot simpler than having to uses curses.

Comment: @GregHewgill interesting solution :-) will probably work on most implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\r` to return the cursor to the start of a line and overwrite the line. So:

```
for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    printf("\rCountdown: %d ", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
printf(" done.\n");
```

The `fflush(stdout);` is necessary because by default, `stdout` only flushes itself when its output buffer gets full, or a `\n` is output.